# Why the MonadReader doesn't require MultiParamTypeClasses and FunctionalDependencies pragma?

Tags: haskell

The `MonadReader` is defined as:

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where {...}
```

in [mtl-2.1.3.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#MonadReader), but the only extension used is `UndecidableInstances`. If I define this in my local, GHC would suggest me to enable `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`.
But why I don't see these two enabled in the mtl source?

Comment: They are in [mtl.cabal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/mtl.cabal) file in the `extensions` section.

Comment: @maxtaldykin No magic at all :(

Comment: The magic is in `UndecidableInstances`

Comment: @maxtaldykin - You should turn that into an answer so Sawyer can make the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are listed in the `extensions` section of [mtl.cabal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/mtl.cabal) file.
Recent versions of `cabal` suggest to split this section into two:

- `default-extensions` will be applied to all files in current target
- `other-extensions` will **not** be applied by default but programmer should explicitly turn them on (with pragma) in each file.